# Autosar - Generating periodic events from single counter

Tags: autosar

I am new to autosar and davinci tool.
I have created an OsCounter object for 1ms. Then gave this counter as reference for two OsAlarm objects named al_10, al_20. On alarm expiry, it is configured to produce events named ev_10, ev_20.

How to configure or where to configure those two events to trigger at 10ms and 20ms respectively?

Comment: Please give some background, what your use-case is to add such counters and alarms manually. In usual cases they are generated automatically when mapping Runnables to Tasks using the "Add Task Mapping" view o DaVinci Configurator Pro.

Comment: The [tag:davinci] tag is not for DaVinci Developer by Vector. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions

1. Create task and implement it manually.
   uint32 b;
   TASK(a)
   {
   getevent(b)
   clearevent(b)
   if(b&mask1)
   do x
   if(b&mask2)
   do y
   }
2. Use RTE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).